# Error 500 while accessing /templeton/v1/jobs with WebHCat

Tags: hadoop

My WebHCat server is running and I can submit a job with hadoop (with the hadoop-example-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar). When I go to

```
http://localhost:8080/templeton/v1/status
```

it's working so the server is up. When I go to

```
http://localhost:8080/templeton/v1/jobs
```

it gives that missing user.name parameter, so I give it the user.name parameter with a GET, but this URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/templeton/v1/jobs?user.name=<username>
```

gives the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /templeton/v1/jobs. Reason:
    org/apache/hadoop/hive/shims/ShimLoader
Powered by Jetty://
```

And if I try to pass it as a POST parameter with

```
curl -s -d "user.name=<username>" 'http://localhost:8080/templeton/v1/jobs'
```

it returns:

```
{"error":null}
```

What can be the problem?

EDIT:

In the webhcat.log:
after POST (with curl)

```
ERROR | 23 Apr 2014 15:21:28,875 | org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.CatchallExceptionMapper |
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:925)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

after GET

```
ERROR | 23 Apr 2014 15:23:27,641 | com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse | The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/shims/ShimLoader
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.ListDelegator.run(ListDelegator.java:44)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.Server.showJobList(Server.java:913)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

WARN  | 23 Apr 2014 15:23:27,642 | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | /templeton/v1/jobs
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/shims/ShimLoader
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.ListDelegator.run(ListDelegator.java:44)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.templeton.Server.showJobList(Server.java:913)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

EDIT 2:
I've put the hive-shims-common-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into the webhcat's svr/lib directory, and now I get the following error:

```
{"error":"Could not load shims in class org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims"}
```

EDIT 3:
If I put also the hive-shims-0.14.0-SNASPHOT.jar, hive-shims-common-secure-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and hive-shims-0.23-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into the folder as I wrote above, both the GET and the POST for v1/jobs results in

```
{"error":null}
```

Does it mean that the given user.name is not valid?

Comment: Do you see additional details on the error in `$HCATALOG_HOME\logs\templeton.log`?

Comment: I've edited my question with the error details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your WebHCat server simply can't find the class mentioned in the error (org/apache/hadoop/hive/shims/ShimLoader).  This class can be found in `hive-shims-0.12.0.2.0.7.0-1551.jar` (Your version may be different) which can be found in Hive's lib dir.

Can you confirm that the process running your WebHCat server has $HIVE_LIB_DIR in its Java $CLASSPATH?

Comment: In my apache-hive directory/lib I can find these related to the hive-shims file: 
hive-shims-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hive-shims-0.20-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hive-shims-0.20S-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hive-shims-0.23-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hive-shims-common-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hive-shims-common-secure-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Sorry, but $HIVE_LIB_DIR as a global linux variable? Or how you mean?